# How do I execute a sed command from a Bash variable?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a sed command that works when executed directly.

```
echo foo > /home/user/bar
sed -i 's/foo/zoo/' /home/user/bar
```

It also works when directly embedded in `$(...)` or `...`.

However, if I try to execute it from a Bash variable, I get an error:

```
CMD="sed -i 's/foo/zoo/' /home/user/bar"
$CMD
```

Error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

It also works if I echo it out and source the file:

```
echo $CMD > file
source file
```

What's going on here, and how do I get the sed command to run from a Bash variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store full command a string variable to avoid word splitting. Use an array or shell function:

```
# store command in an array
cmd=(sed -i 's/foo/zoo/' /home/user/bar)

# execute the command
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Or else use a shell function:

```
fn() {
   sed -i 's/foo/zoo/' /home/user/bar
}

#call it as:
fn
```

[Read this BASH FAQ: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Both of these work, but I'm curious why the string version does not work?  The string version is a bit more readable to a Bash novice

Comment: Storing command in a string variable and executing it later causes word splitting especially when quotes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

use `eval` : I am not sure why you want to do it. Note that using `eval` is a fragil solution and can cause your script to broke.

```
eval $CMD
```